# App crashes when using a recursive function

Tags: android, multithreading, crash, runnable, java-threads

I'm wrote a function to scan for all the directories/files for audio files and if any audio file is found, it is added to media store. So, while scanning I set the path of the directory/file to a textview. All this happen when a button is clicked. Now, the problem is when I click the button the app freezes for a while and then crashes (although the paths of directories and files are printed in logcat). I assume this happens because it is a heavy task and it is running on the main thread. So what I tried:

1) Creating a new thread
2) Delaying the handler and invoking function after N seconds
3) Using AsyncTask

Everything one the above resulted in a crash with errora:

1) `Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 12727.2ms.)`

2).  `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@e22c464 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Code:

```
 public void rescanForMedia(View view) {



    AlertDialog.Builder rescanInit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.dialog_mediascanner, null);
    rescanInit.setView(v);

    Button  mediaScanButton = v.findViewById(R.id.mediaScanButton);

    mediaScaninitBox = rescanInit.create();
    mediaScaninitBox.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mediaScaninitBox.show();

    mediaScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Scan Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AlertDialog.Builder rescanRunningBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(SettingsActivity.this);
            View v = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.dialog_scanning, null);
            rescanRunningBox.setView(v);
            mediaScanRunningBox = rescanRunningBox.create();
            mediaScanRunningBox.show();
            scannedFiles = v.findViewById(R.id.scannedFiles);
            mediaScaninitBox.dismiss();
            walkDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());


        }
    });



}

public void walkDir(File file){

    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (final File filess : files) {
            // checking the File is file or directory

         //    scannedFiles.setText(path);



            if (filess.isFile()) {
                path = filess.getAbsolutePath();

                        scannedFiles.setText(path);

                //   Log.v("Files: ",path);

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        new String[]{path},
                        new String[]{"audio/*"},
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                                mediaScanRunningBox.dismiss();

                            }
                        });

            }
            else{
                //if it is a directory

                walkDir(filess);





            }
```

Comment: use threads or asynctask for longer running processes

Comment: recursive function may produce Stackoverflow exception

Comment: Can you suggest changes that can be made to the code to avoid the crash?

Comment: `mediaScanRunningBox.dismiss();`. For every file found you dissmiss a box. Why? Makes no sense. Further i dont understand that you create two alert boxes. And why putting all filenames in a text view? The user will only see the last one. And why invoking the mediascanner for every file found and creating a new on complete listener? What is t that you want? The media scanner will have known these files already.

Comment: Two alertboxes -one for asking user for confirmation and if users presses "Start", the scanning begins and progress is shown in second alertbox. I'm calling mediaScanner to add any audio files that have not been added to mediastore. TextView shows the directory/file currently being scanned